# How to read the result of SELECT * from joined tables with duplicate column names in .NET

Tags: c#, join

I am a PHP/MySQL developer, slowly venturing into the realm of C#/SQL Server and I am having a problem in C# when it comes to reading an SQL Server query that joins two tables.

Given the two tables:

TableA:

```
int:id
VARCHAR(50):name
int:b_id
```

TableB:

```
int:id
VARCHAR(50):name
```

And given the query

```
SELECT * FROM TableA,TableB WHERE TableA.b_id = TableB.id;
```

Now in C# I normally read query data in the following fashion:

```
SqlDataReader data_reader= sql_command.ExecuteReader();
data_reader["Field"];
```

Except in this case I need to differentiate from TableA's name column, and TableB's name column.

In PHP I would simply ask for the field "TableA.name" or "TableB.name" accordingly but when I try something like

```
data_reader["TableB.name"];
```

in C#, my code errors out.

How can fix this? And how can I read a query on multiple tables in C#?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get values from joined tables using SqlDataReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065354/get-values-from-joined-tables-using-sqldatareader)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result set only sees the returned data/column names, not the underlying table.  Change your query to something like

```
SELECT TableA.Name as Name_TA, TableB.Name as Name_TB from ...
```

Then you can refer to the fields like this:

```
data_reader["Name_TA"];
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. That is one solution, but I am not a fan of it because before the query I have to know every conflicting field name and specify the switch in my query. Is there a way to perform a function that renames all the TableA values with the suffix _TA or something like it?

Comment: To elaborate, anything you could do that would "automatically" rename the result columns would involve you specifying the name somewhere.  You could create a view or stored procedure, maybe if you were really good create some dynamic SQL... but at some point you're going to be doing table.field AS newName to disambiguate.

Comment: In general, you should avoid "SELECT *", and spell out field names explicitly. This issue is just one of the reasons why.

Comment: you would have to know every conflicting field **anyway** to read the fields the way you were doing it before

Answer (score 3):

To those posting that it is wrong to use "SELECT *", I strongly disagree with you.  There are many real world cases where a SELECT * is necessary.  Your absolute statements about its "wrong" use may be leading someone astray from what is a legitimate solution.

The problem here does not lie with the use of SELECT *, but with a constraint in [ADO.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET).

As the OP points out, in PHP you can index a data row via the "TABLE.COLUMN" syntax, which is also how raw SQL handles column name conflicts:

> SELECT table1.ID, table2.ID FROM table1, table;

Why DataReader is not implemented this way I do not know...

That said, a solution to be used could build your SQL statement dynamically by:

- querying the schema of the tables you're selecting from
- build your SELECT clause by iterating through the column names in the schema

In this way you could build a query like the following without having to know what columns currently exist in the schema for the tables you're selecting from

> SELECT TableA.Name as Name_TA, TableB.Name as Name_TB from ...

Answer (score 1):

You could try reading the values by index (a number) rather than by key.

```
name = data_reader[4];
```

You will have to experiment to see how the numbers correspond.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the real world. In the real world, we don't use "SELECT *". Specify which columns you want, from which tables, and with which alias, if required.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is better to use a column list to remove duplicate columns, if for any reason you want *****, then just use

```
rdr.item("duplicate_column_name")
```

This will return the first column value, since the inner join will have the same values in both identical columns, so this will accomplish the task.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, you should never have duplicate column names, across a database schema. So if you can rename your schema to not have conflicting names.

That rule is for this very situation. Once you've done your join, it is just a new recordset, and generally the table names do go with it.

Comment: Strongly disagree with him, actually...  For instance I like to have an ID column on every table.  That way you know what the primary key column is without ever having to look, even if you've never queried that table before.

Comment: Sorry, your friend is wrong. The correct answer is "don't use SELECT *"

Comment: Disagree as well. Also, we often have to deal with data we did not architect.