# Get values from joined tables using SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, sqldatareader

Imagine we have two tables in the database, `user` (FK id_role) and `role` (PK role). We need to read information about user and his privileges.

I use the following SQL statement to perform query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [user] 
INNER JOIN role ON [user].id_role = role.id 
WHERE login = @login
```

After executing, I try to read values in reader using string indexer: `reader[string name]`.

The problem which I need to resolve is repeating names: both `user` and `role` contain, e.g., the field `id`, which I am able to read for user (using `reader["id"]`), but not able to read for role (using `reader["role.id"]`).

The property `FieldCount` returns 12, which means that all required fields were read (`user` contains 6 fields, so does `role`).

Do I have a possibility to read columns by name in this case? Or using two queries or SQL 'as' operator in the only way?

Comment: You need to define column aliases in your `SELECT` - or read by ordinal position (`Reader[index]`) - but that of course is prone to other problems (like `User` table gets one more property and then your orders are all off by 1) - and those could be solved by not using `SELECT *` - but explicitly listing all the columns you really need and want to select from those two tables...

Comment: Of course reading by position is uncomfortable a bit... Probably aliases is the answer. But I'm confused why datareader doesn't add table name before columns.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could always select the columns explicitly and alias them:

```
SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.*, role.id AS role_id, role.* 
FROM [user] 
INNER JOIN role ON [user].id_role = role.id 
WHERE login = @login
```

Then select them with `reader["user_id"]` and `reader["role_id"]`.

Comment: Just a curiosity to know: does it show user_id column two times? and same for the role_id column?? Thanks.

Comment: @sarwar026, yeah, in what I wrote there both ID columns would be selected twice.

Comment: It's a nice way and probably the easiest one, thanks! I guess the best way to avoid such problems is to provide tables' columns with unique names.

Answer (score 1):

The only robust way is to use `AS` in the SQL-query to make sure your column names/aliases are unique... otherwise you would to access the fields by index (0 / 1 / 2 etc.) instead of by name.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT role.id as RoleId, user.id as UserId
FROM [user] 
INNER JOIN role ON [user].id_role = role.id 
WHERE login = @login
```

Using AS

```
reader["RoleId"];
```

Comment: Is there a solution not using `AS`?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you should select columns by name, but you need to do it like:

```
SELECT u.id as uid, r.id as rid, ... , FROM [user] u INNER JOIN role r ON [user].id_role = role.id WHERE login = @login
```

With **, ... ,**  I want to select the remaining column of both the tables.

Finally, use reader["uid"], reader["rid"] etc.